# iText.Kernel.PdfException: 'Document was closed. It is impossible to execute action.' itext7 version 7.1.7

Tags: c#, unit-testing, pdf, .net-core, itext7

Error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'
>
> page was null.

I don't really know what to do now, a page should be created when I'm running this:

```cs
         [Fact]
      public void HandleEvent_Renders_Properly()
      {
          var ir = new TestIllustrationReport().Report;
          var reportProperties = new TestDocument().ReportProperties;
          var sec = new FooterSection(new ProductContent(ir));
          sec.Build();
          Dictionary<int, TagTreeInfo> dict = new Dictionary<int, TagTreeInfo>();
          reportProperties.FooterTag=dict;
          FooterEventHandler footerEvent = new FooterEventHandler(sec, reportProperties);
          bool called = false;

          // Must have write permissions to the path folder
          var path = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
          var fileName = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension("Test", ".pdf");
          var com = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName);
          PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(com);
          PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

          iText.Layout.Document document = new iText.Layout.Document(pdf);
          
          Paragraph header = new Paragraph("HEADER")
       .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
       .SetFontSize(20);

          document.Add(header);
          pdf.SetTagged();
          pdf.GetCatalog().SetViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().SetDisplayDocTitle(true));
          pdf.GetCatalog().SetLang(new PdfString("en-US"));
          PdfDocumentInfo info = pdf.GetDocumentInfo();
          info.SetTitle("Testing tags");

          Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Tested");
          p.GetAccessibilityProperties().SetRole("H");
          Div divH = new Div().Add(p);
          Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Child H1");
          p2.GetAccessibilityProperties().SetRole("H1");
          Div divH1 = new Div().Add(p2);
          divH1.Add(new Paragraph("Testing ChildChild"));
          divH.Add(divH1);
          document.Add(divH);
          document.Close();

          PdfDocumentEvent eventK = new PdfDocumentEvent("pdf",pdf);

          // Act 
          footerEvent.HandleEvent(eventK); // the exception happens when I go into this method
          

          // Assert 
          Assert.True(called);

      }
```

into the HandleEvent Method

```
     public void HandleEvent(Event @event)
        {
            var docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
            var pdfDoc = docEvent.GetDocument();
            var page = docEvent.GetPage();

            PageNumber = pdfDoc.GetPageNumber(page);//iText.Kernel.PdfException: 'Document was closed. It is impossible to execute action.'
            var pageNumberParagraph = new LightParagraph(string.Format(FooterSection.PageNumberXofY.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, PageNumber), FontSize.Weight8, FontUtil);  
            pageNumberParagraph.GetAccessibilityProperties().SetRole(StandardRoles.ARTIFACT);
           var autoP = pdfDoc.GetTagStructureContext().GetAutoTaggingPointer();
            var posBackup = new TagTreePointer(autoP);
            PagesTag.TryGetValue(PageNumber, out TagTreeInfo p);
            if (p?.TagTreePointer != null)
            {
           
                int indexInParentKidsList = p.TagTreePointer.GetIndexInParentKidsList();
                autoP.MoveToPointer(p.TagTreePointer).MoveToParent();
                
                if (p.Tagged)
                {
                    autoP.SetNextNewKidIndex(indexInParentKidsList + 1);
                }
            }

            var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.GetLastContentStream(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
            try
            {

                var rect = new Rectangle(pdfDoc.GetDefaultPageSize().GetX() + FooterDocument.GetLeftMargin(),
                                         FooterSection.Content.PageMargin,
                                         -Width.Size50,
                                         TableHeight);

                using Canvas canvas = new(pdfCanvas, pdfDoc, rect);

                canvas.EnableAutoTagging(page);
                //  check to see if which specific tagged footer needs to be shown
                Div footer = null;
                if (PagesTag.Count != PageNumber && PagesTag.Count > PageNumber)
                {
                    footer = ArtifactFooter;
                    canvas.Add(footer);
                    var placeHolder = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(0, 0, Side, Side));
                    PlaceHolders.Add(placeHolder);
                    pdfCanvas.AddXObject(placeHolder, X, Y - Descent, 1, true);
                }
                else if (PagesTag.Count == PageNumber)// Only for one page scenario
                {
                    footer = DivFooter;
                    canvas.Add(footer);
                }
                else
                {
                    // no action required
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                pdfCanvas.Release();
            }

            if (p?.TagTreePointer != null)
            {
               
                autoP.MoveToPointer(posBackup);
            }
        }
```

This is a unit test for the HandleEvent method, so I created all the set up to create the pdf the pdf is working right now I'm able to see the tags, divs, paragraphs, header. So, right now this is failing when I call the HandleEvent  like "footerEvent.HandleEvent(eventK)". please see the method comment where is failing.

Comment: On which line of your code do you get that exception?

Comment: I edited my question, and when I checked on the page is null when I go into public void HandleEvent(Event @event)
        {
            var docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
            var pdfDoc = docEvent.GetDocument();
            var page = docEvent.GetPage();

Comment: I moved the document.Close() to put below the document.Add(divH). So, the pdf is properly executed, but now I get an error... iText.Kernel.PdfException: 'Document was closed. It is impossible to execute action.'

Comment: we don't see how are assigned some variables, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I updated it, hope this is better.

Comment: Just prior to creating the `eventk` variable, the pdf document is closed with `document.Close();` - I suspect this is why the event handler is now throwing an exception for the document being closed.

Comment: yeah I know that, but if I don't close it the pdf isn't created properly, if I close it after calling the method I get a page was null at var pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.GetLastContentStream(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);

Comment: Just like @Metro mentioned, closing the `Document` closes also the underlying `PdfDocument` and so finalizes the document. After that accessing those objects is bound to fail.

Comment: Also event handlers aren't meant to be called manually, they are meant to be called by the frame work, iText in this case.

Comment: ohhh I didn't know, so how can I test that this method has been called? because I can't see any reference to it anywhere in the code :(